# Webflux is there a way to use websocket with stomp and sockjs

Tags: websocket, spring-webflux, stomp, sockjs

Is there a way to use websocket in spring boot webflux with stomp and sockjs?  All the examples I have found are showing Websocket handler approach.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550768/why-does-stomp-functionality-in-spring-websocket-depend-on-spring-mvc